# How to get rid of EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, memory, exc-bad-access, navigationcontroller

So, another EXC_BAD_ACCESS topic on StackOverflow, but as I'm new to Objective-C this is still a topic I don't really grasp yet. Even though I have done a lot of research about it already.

The issue is the following. I have a `UIScrollView` that I have overwritten using a Custom Class (named **MultiSelectView**). If the user taps this `UIScrollView` and then I want to open a view that allows him to select some data.

So I have declared a `UITapGestureRecognizer` that calls the `openMultiSelect:` method. But on the line `[parent.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];` I get a `Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".` error. Why o why?

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *) coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder: coder];

    if (self) {
        // Add a Tap Gesture Recognizer to the Scrollview.
        // If the user taps the view, it triggers the 'openMultiSelect' method.
        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openMultiSelect:)];
        [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [singleTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)openMultiSelect:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    //int myViewTag = gesture.view.tag;  // now you know which view called

    DataSelectView *view = [[DataSelectView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DataSelectView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    view.allowMultiSelect = YES;

    [parent.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
    [view release];
}
```

So the `parent` that you see is a ViewController that contains the tab. Is there a better way to do this? Because for now I have thus a ViewController that contains Tabs. In its `activateTab:` method I thus create the tab and pass `self` along. I do the same in the `viewDidLoad` for that tab to pass the `parent` to the custom `UIScrollView`:

```
- (void) activateTab:(int)index {
   ... code ...

   self.tab_Basic = [[TabBasic alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabBasic" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
   self.tab_Basic.parent = self;

   ... code ...
}
```

Comment: I found that enabling NSZombieEnabled really helped me in debugging. Obj-C can be quite confusing :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is releasing the object "view" too early, don't release it until the view is popped. That should fix the problem.

```
- (void)openMultiSelect:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
//int myViewTag = gesture.view.tag;  // now you know which view called

DataSelectView *view = [[DataSelectView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DataSelectView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
view.allowMultiSelect = YES;

[parent.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

Comment: Even when leaving out my `[view release];` the program still crashes with the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error on `[parent.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];`...

Comment: when debugging, when xcode shows up and highlights the line, hover your mouse over view, and parent and check to make sure they both are not equal to nil.

Comment: They are not equal to nil. Both have a memory address and I can view their properties etc.

Comment: Try making parent a property of self like so @property (retain, assign) id parent; and then synthesize it.

Comment: My parent is a property, declared as `@property (nonatomic, retain) PropertyViewController *parent;`.

Comment: then change parent.navigationController to self.parent.navigationController  Maybe that will work...

Comment: @Jules let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1635/discussion-between-macintosh264-and-jules)

Comment: I fixed the problem after enabling the NSZombie mode. So that certainly helped me. It was due to some object that was being released in another class which i was still using somewhere else though. Tnx for thinking along! So this answer didn't solve it, but I tick it as correct because you helped me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should make some change to your callback method. Something like that:

```
- (void)openMultiSelect:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    //int myViewTag = gesture.view.tag;  // now you know which view called
    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        DataSelectView *view = [[DataSelectView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DataSelectView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        view.allowMultiSelect = YES;

        [parent.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
        [view release];
    }
}
```

Comment: I added that but it doesn't change anything. Still EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Isn't there a way to get more information from Xcode about which object is causing this etc..?

Comment: Hmm... then try to use history_malloc as described [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingAutorelease) to get more info...